# How can I save the information when toggling for the element.empty() function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$("#prop-info-nav-link").click(function() {
  $("#toggle-content-add-modal").empty();
  let output = '<div class="row g-0 justify-content-center prop-info-row"><div class="col-md-8 prop-info-col"><p style="font-weight: 600;">Property Type</p></div><div class="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-center prop-info-col"><select name="property-types" id="property-types"><option value="volvo">Tenament</option><option value="saab">Car</option><option value="opel" selected>Helicopter</option><option value="audi">Space Shuttle</option></select><div class="input-group mb-3 ms-3"><span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">OR</span><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-prop-type" placeholder="Enter a new type" aria-label="Property-Type" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" autocomplete="off"></div></div><div class="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-center prop-info-col mt-5"><input type="text" id="prop-name" class="add-inpt" placeholder="Property Name"></div><div class="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-center prop-info-col mt-3"><input type="text" id="prop-address" class="add-inpt" placeholder="Property Address"></div></div>';
  $("#toggle-content-add-modal").html(output);
});

$("#img-nav-link").click(function() {
  $("#toggle-content-add-modal").empty();
  let output = '<!-- UPLOAD IMAGE SECTION --><div id="uploadArea" class="upload-area"><!-- Header --><div class="upload-area__header"><h1 class="upload-area__title">Upload your file</h1><p class="upload-area__paragraph">File should be an image<strong class="upload-area__tooltip">Like<span class="upload-area__tooltip-data"></span><!-- Data Will Come From Js --></strong></p></div><!-- End Header --><!-- Drop Zoon --><div id="dropZoon" class="upload-area__drop-zoon drop-zoon"><span class="drop-zoon__icon"><i class="bx bxs-file-image"></i></span><p class="drop-zoon__paragraph">Drop your file here or Click to browse</p><span id="loadingText" class="drop-zoon__loading-text">Please Wait</span><img src="" alt="Preview Image" id="previewImage" class="drop-zoon__preview-image" draggable="false"><input type="file" id="fileInput" class="drop-zoon__file-input" accept="image/*"></div><!-- End Drop Zoon --><!-- File Details --><div id="fileDetails" class="upload-area__file-details file-details"><div id="uploadedFile" class="uploaded-file"><div class="uploaded-file__icon-container"><i class="bx bxs-file-blank uploaded-file__icon"></i><span class="uploaded-file__icon-text"></span><!-- Data Will be Comes From Js --></div><div id="uploadedFileInfo" class="uploaded-file__info"><span class="uploaded-file__name">Project 1</span><span class="uploaded-file__counter">0%</span></div></div></div><!-- End File Details --></div></div><!-- End Upload Area -->';
  $("#toggle-content-add-modal").html(output);
});

$(function () {
    $(".side-nav li").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".side-nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
/* Add property modal */

.add-property {
  position: relative;
  width: 60rem;
  height: 35rem;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.modal-title {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.close {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

#footer-btn {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.add-prop {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
}

.add-prop:hover {
  background-color: rgb(12, 65, 180);
}

.add-inpt {
  outline: none;
  border-width: 0 0 0.17em;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 15em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.prop-info-row {
  height: 15em;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.prop-info-col {
  height: 2em;
}

.add-inpt::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-add-row {
  width: 50rem;
  height: 26rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

#property-types {
  background-color: white;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 13em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* SIDE NAV INSIDE ADD PROPERTY MODAL */
.side-nav,
.nav-menu {
    height: 100%;
}

.side-nav .nav-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 40px 0;
    width: 13em;
    background-color: #3498db;

}

.side-nav .nav-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.7em 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: 42%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.nav-item.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav-item.active a {
    color: #2980b9;
}

.nav-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu-text {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.side-nav .nav-item.active::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 150%;
    width: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 0 0 #fff;
}

.side-nav .nav-item.active::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 150%;
    width: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 -20px 0 0 #fff;
}

/* UPLOAD IMAGE STYLE */
:root {
    --clr-white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --clr-black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    --clr-light: rgb(245, 248, 255);
    --clr-light-gray: rgb(196, 195, 196);
    --clr-blue: rgb(63, 134, 255);
    --clr-light-blue: rgb(171, 202, 255);
}

/* End General Styles */

/* Upload Area */
.upload-area {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25rem;
    background-color: var(--clr-white);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(218, 229, 255);
    border: 2px solid var(--clr-light-blue);
    border-radius: 24px;
    padding: 1rem 1.875rem 0rem 1.875rem;
    margin: 0.625rem;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Header */
.upload-area__title {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 0.3125rem;
}

.upload-area__paragraph {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    color: var(--clr-light-gray);
    margin-top: 0;
}

.upload-area__tooltip {
    position: relative;
    color: var(--clr-light-blue);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.upload-area__tooltip:hover {
    color: var(--clr-blue);
}

.upload-area__tooltip-data {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -125%);
    min-width: max-content;
    background-color: var(--clr-white);
    color: var(--clr-blue);
    border: 1px solid var(--clr-light-blue);
    padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: none 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
}

.upload-area__tooltip:hover .upload-area__tooltip-data {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* Drop Zoon */
.upload-area__drop-zoon {
    position: relative;
    height: 13.8rem;
    /* 180px */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 2px dashed var(--clr-light-blue);
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 1.1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: border-color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.upload-area__drop-zoon:hover {
    border-color: var(--clr-blue);
}

.drop-zoon__icon {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    color: var(--clr-blue);
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.drop-zoon__paragraph {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    color: var(--clr-light-gray);
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0.625rem;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.drop-zoon:hover .drop-zoon__icon,
.drop-zoon:hover .drop-zoon__paragraph {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.drop-zoon__loading-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: none;
    color: var(--clr-light-blue);
    z-index: 10;
}

.drop-zoon__preview-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    padding: 0.3125rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.drop-zoon:hover .drop-zoon__preview-image {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.drop-zoon__file-input {
    display: none;
}

/* (drop-zoon--over) Modifier Class */
.drop-zoon--over {
    border-color: var(--clr-blue);
}

.drop-zoon--over .drop-zoon__icon,
.drop-zoon--over .drop-zoon__paragraph {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

/* (drop-zoon--over) Modifier Class */

.drop-zoon--Uploaded .drop-zoon__icon,
.drop-zoon--Uploaded .drop-zoon__paragraph {
    display: none;
}

/* File Details Area */
.upload-area__file-details {
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    transition: none 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-delay: 500ms;
}

/* (duploaded-file--open) Modifier Class */
.file-details--open {
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Uploaded File */
.uploaded-file {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.925rem 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: none 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition-property: visibility, opacity;
}

/* (duploaded-file--open) Modifier Class */
.uploaded-file--open {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.uploaded-file__icon-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0.3125rem;
}

.uploaded-file__icon {
    font-size: 3.4375rem;
    color: var(--clr-blue);
}

.uploaded-file__icon-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5625rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--clr-white);
}

.uploaded-file__info {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.3125rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.uploaded-file__info::before,
.uploaded-file__info::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.9375rem;
    width: 0;
    height: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #ebf2ff;
    border-radius: 0.625rem;
}

.uploaded-file__info::before {
    width: 100%;
}

.uploaded-file__info::after {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--clr-blue);
}

/* Progress Animation */
.uploaded-file__info--active::after {
    animation: progressMove 800ms ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 300ms;
}

@keyframes progressMove {
    from {
        width: 0%;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    to {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: var(--clr-blue);
    }
}

.uploaded-file__name {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 6.25rem;
    /* 100px */
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.uploaded-file__counter {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--clr-light-gray);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalAddProperty" class="add-more" id="add-property">Add
            Property</button>

<!-- Modal window for Add Property button -->
<form action="">
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAddProperty" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content add-property">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add Property</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 0;">
          <div class="row g-0 main-add-row">

            <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding: 0;">
              <nav class="side-nav">
                <ul class="nav-menu">
                  <li class="nav-item active" id="img-nav-link">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-file-arrow-up"></i>
                      <span class="menu-text">Upload Image</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" id="prop-info-nav-link">
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney-crack"></i>
                      <span class="menu-text">Propery Info</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-9 d-flex justify-content-center" id="toggle-content-add-modal">
              <!-- UPLOAD IMAGE SECTION -->
              <div id="uploadArea" class="upload-area">
                <!-- Header -->
                <div class="upload-area__header">
                  <h1 class="upload-area__title">Upload your file</h1>
                  <p class="upload-area__paragraph">
                    File should be an image
                    <strong class="upload-area__tooltip">
                                                Like
                                                <span class="upload-area__tooltip-data"></span>
                                                <!-- Data Will Come From Js -->
                                            </strong>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <!-- End Header -->

                <!-- Drop Zoon -->
                <div id="dropZoon" class="upload-area__drop-zoon drop-zoon">
                  <span class="drop-zoon__icon">
                                            <i class='bx bxs-file-image'></i>
                                        </span>
                  <p class="drop-zoon__paragraph">Drop your file here or Click to browse</p>
                  <span id="loadingText" class="drop-zoon__loading-text">Please Wait</span>
                  <img src="" alt="Preview Image" id="previewImage" class="drop-zoon__preview-image" draggable="false">
                  <input type="file" id="fileInput" class="drop-zoon__file-input" accept="image/*">
                </div>
                <!-- End Drop Zoon -->

                <!-- File Details -->
                <div id="fileDetails" class="upload-area__file-details file-details">
                  <div id="uploadedFile" class="uploaded-file">
                    <div class="uploaded-file__icon-container">
                      <i class='bx bxs-file-blank uploaded-file__icon'></i>
                      <span class="uploaded-file__icon-text"></span>
                      <!-- Data Will be Comes From Js -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="uploadedFileInfo" class="uploaded-file__info">
                      <span class="uploaded-file__name">Project 1</span>
                      <span class="uploaded-file__counter">0%</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End File Details -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Upload Area -->

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-ftr">
          <button type="submit" class="add-prop" id="footer-btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The modal looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the `Property Info`, all the child elements in the a column: `#toggle-content-add-modal` related to `Upload Image` is deleted with the help of `$("#toggle-content-add-modal").empty()` and replaced by the elements related to `Property Info`.

[image]

This `.empty()` and and `.html()` is, in a way toggled when clicking respective `nav-links` (Upload Image and Property Info). But the data I entered like uploading the image or any information in the `Property Info` gets deleted also. I know `.empty()` specifically does that. But I cant find any other option in which the data is stored when toggling between `nav-links`.

Comment: Have you tried [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)ing the elements rather than removing them?  The .show() to bring them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to just "toggle" some sections, then there is no need to manually add and remove anything from the DOM. You can do this instead

- First, add all the sections to the page.
- Hide the ones you don't want to make visible when the page loads.
- Add `data-target="id-of-targeted-side-nav-li"` to each section.

Try this

```js
$(function () {
    $(".side-nav li").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let id = $(this).attr('id');

        // toggle sidebar nav
        $(".side-nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // toggle sidebar nav target
        $('#toggle-content-add-modal')
            .children().hide()
            .filter((i, elem) => $(elem).data('target') === id)
            .show();
    });
});
```

```css
/* Add property modal */

.add-property {
    position: relative;
    width: 60rem;
    height: 35rem;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.modal-title {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.close {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}

#footer-btn {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border: 0.1em solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}

.add-prop {
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
}

.add-prop:hover {
    background-color: rgb(12, 65, 180);
}

.add-inpt {
    outline: none;
    border-width: 0 0 0.17em;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 15em;
    height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.prop-info-row {
    height: 15em;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.prop-info-col {
    height: 2em;
}

.add-inpt::placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}

.main-add-row {
    width: 50rem;
    height: 26rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

#property-types {
    background-color: white;
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 13em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* SIDE NAV INSIDE ADD PROPERTY MODAL */
.side-nav,
.nav-menu {
    height: 100%;
}

.side-nav .nav-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 40px 0;
    width: 13em;
    background-color: #3498db;

}

.side-nav .nav-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.7em 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: 42%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.nav-item.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav-item.active a {
    color: #2980b9;
}

.nav-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu-text {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.side-nav .nav-item.active::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 150%;
    width: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 0 0 #fff;
}

.side-nav .nav-item.active::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 150%;
    width: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 -20px 0 0 #fff;
}

/* UPLOAD IMAGE STYLE */
:root {
    --clr-white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --clr-black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    --clr-light: rgb(245, 248, 255);
    --clr-light-gray: rgb(196, 195, 196);
    --clr-blue: rgb(63, 134, 255);
    --clr-light-blue: rgb(171, 202, 255);
}

/* End General Styles */

/* Upload Area */
.upload-area {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25rem;
    background-color: var(--clr-white);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(218, 229, 255);
    border: 2px solid var(--clr-light-blue);
    border-radius: 24px;
    padding: 1rem 1.875rem 0rem 1.875rem;
    margin: 0.625rem;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Header */
.upload-area__title {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 0.3125rem;
}

.upload-area__paragraph {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    color: var(--clr-light-gray);
    margin-top: 0;
}

.upload-area__tooltip {
    position: relative;
    color: var(--clr-light-blue);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.upload-area__tooltip:hover {
    color: var(--clr-blue);
}

.upload-area__tooltip-data {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -125%);
    min-width: max-content;
    background-color: var(--clr-white);
    color: var(--clr-blue);
    border: 1px solid var(--clr-light-blue);
    padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: none 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
}

.upload-area__tooltip:hover .upload-area__tooltip-data {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* Drop Zoon */
.upload-area__drop-zoon {
    position: relative;
    height: 13.8rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 2px dashed var(--clr-light-blue);
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 1.1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: border-color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.upload-area__drop-zoon:hover {
    border-color: var(--clr-blue);
}

.drop-zoon__icon {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    color: var(--clr-blue);
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.drop-zoon__paragraph {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    color: var(--clr-light-gray);
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0.625rem;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.drop-zoon:hover .drop-zoon__icon,
.drop-zoon:hover .drop-zoon__paragraph {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.drop-zoon__loading-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: none;
    color: var(--clr-light-blue);
    z-index: 10;
}

.drop-zoon__preview-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    padding: 0.3125rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.drop-zoon:hover .drop-zoon__preview-image {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.drop-zoon__file-input {
    display: none;
}

/* (drop-zoon--over) Modifier Class */
.drop-zoon--over {
    border-color: var(--clr-blue);
}

.drop-zoon--over .drop-zoon__icon,
.drop-zoon--over .drop-zoon__paragraph {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

/* (drop-zoon--over) Modifier Class */

.drop-zoon--Uploaded .drop-zoon__icon,
.drop-zoon--Uploaded .drop-zoon__paragraph {
    display: none;
}

/* File Details Area */
.upload-area__file-details {
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    transition: none 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-delay: 500ms;
}

/* (duploaded-file--open) Modifier Class */
.file-details--open {
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Uploaded File */
.uploaded-file {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.925rem 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: none 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition-property: visibility, opacity;
}

/* (duploaded-file--open) Modifier Class */
.uploaded-file--open {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.uploaded-file__icon-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0.3125rem;
}

.uploaded-file__icon {
    font-size: 3.4375rem;
    color: var(--clr-blue);
}

.uploaded-file__icon-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5625rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--clr-white);
}

.uploaded-file__info {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.3125rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.uploaded-file__info::before,
.uploaded-file__info::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.9375rem;
    width: 0;
    height: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #ebf2ff;
    border-radius: 0.625rem;
}

.uploaded-file__info::before {
    width: 100%;
}

.uploaded-file__info::after {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--clr-blue);
}

/* Progress Animation */
.uploaded-file__info--active::after {
    animation: progressMove 800ms ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 300ms;
}

@keyframes progressMove {
    from {
        width: 0%;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    to {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: var(--clr-blue);
    }
}

.uploaded-file__name {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 6.25rem;
/* 100px */
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1rem;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.uploaded-file__counter {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: var(--clr-light-gray);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalAddProperty" class="add-more" id="add-property">Add
            Property</button>

<!-- Modal window for Add Property button -->
<form action="">
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAddProperty" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content add-property">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add Property</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 0;">
                    <div class="row g-0 main-add-row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding: 0;">
                            <nav class="side-nav">
                                <ul class="nav-menu">
                                    <li class="nav-item active" id="img-nav-link">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-file-arrow-up"></i>
                                            <span class="menu-text">Upload Image</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item" id="prop-info-nav-link">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney-crack"></i>
                                            <span class="menu-text">Propery Info</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 d-flex justify-content-center" id="toggle-content-add-modal">
                            <!-- UPLOAD IMAGE SECTION -->
                            <div id="uploadArea" class="upload-area" data-target="img-nav-link">
                                <!-- Header -->
                                <div class="upload-area__header">
                                    <h1 class="upload-area__title">Upload your file</h1>
                                    <p class="upload-area__paragraph">
                                        File should be an image
                                        <strong class="upload-area__tooltip">
                                            Like
                                            <span class="upload-area__tooltip-data"></span>
                                            <!-- Data Will Come From Js -->
                                        </strong>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Header -->

                                <!-- Drop Zoon -->
                                <div id="dropZoon" class="upload-area__drop-zoon drop-zoon">
                                    <span class="drop-zoon__icon">
                                        <i class='bx bxs-file-image'></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <p class="drop-zoon__paragraph">Drop your file here or Click to browse</p>
                                    <span id="loadingText" class="drop-zoon__loading-text">Please Wait</span>
                                    <img src="" alt="Preview Image" id="previewImage" class="drop-zoon__preview-image" draggable="false">
                                    <input type="file" id="fileInput" class="drop-zoon__file-input" accept="image/*">
                                </div>
                                <!-- End Drop Zoon -->

                                <!-- File Details -->
                                <div id="fileDetails" class="upload-area__file-details file-details">
                                    <div id="uploadedFile" class="uploaded-file">
                                        <div class="uploaded-file__icon-container">
                                            <i class='bx bxs-file-blank uploaded-file__icon'></i>
                                            <span class="uploaded-file__icon-text"></span>
                                            <!-- Data Will be Comes From Js -->
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="uploadedFileInfo" class="uploaded-file__info">
                                            <span class="uploaded-file__name">Project 1</span>
                                            <span class="uploaded-file__counter">0%</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- End File Details -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Upload Area -->

                            <!-- Prop Info Section -->
                            <div class="row g-0 justify-content-center prop-info-row" data-target="prop-info-nav-link" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="col-md-8 prop-info-col">
                                    <p style="font-weight: 600;">Property Type</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-center prop-info-col">
                                    <select name="property-types" id="property-types">
                                        <option value="volvo">Tenament</option>
                                        <option value="saab">Car</option>
                                        <option value="opel" selected>Helicopter</option>
                                        <option value="audi">Space Shuttle</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3 ms-3">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">OR</span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-prop-type" placeholder="Enter a new type" aria-label="Property-Type" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-center prop-info-col mt-5">
                                    <input type="text" id="prop-name" class="add-inpt" placeholder="Property Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-center prop-info-col mt-3">
                                    <input type="text" id="prop-address" class="add-inpt" placeholder="Property Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Prop Info Section -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-ftr">
                    <button type="submit" class="add-prop" id="footer-btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, your idea is great. It is working following your idea. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the child elements you're removing by using [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`detach`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/):

```
const children = $("#toggle-content-add-modal").children().detach();
```

That removes them from the document but returns a jQuery object containing them, so you can put them back later with [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Here's a simplified example:

```js
$("input[type=text]").on("change input", (e) => {
    $("#echo").text(e.currentTarget.value);
});

let children = null;
$("input[type=button]").on("click", () => {
    if (children) {
        $("#container").append(children);
        children = null;
    } else {
        children = $("#container").children().detach();
    }
});
```

```css
.echo {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
    min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Toggle">
<div>
Type something in the input box below, which will be echoed to a div under it, and then use the toggle button above to show removing and restoring the content (including the input's value and the "echo" div's text):
</div>
<hr>
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <label>
            Type something here:
            <input type="text" value="">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        You've typed:
        <div id="echo"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am new to Javascript. Your idea seems great.  I tried it, added two `const` variable `children1` and `children2`. I replaced `$("#toggle-content-add-modal").empty();` line in my code with `const children = $("#toggle-content-add-modal").children().detach();`. But it didnt work. Also the code didnt run as it does in the above snippet. How should I proceed with the Javascript part?

Comment: @MeetGondaliya - I've added a simplified example to the answer. I'm afraid I don't have time to read through your code and figure out what you're trying to do with it. Fundamentally, if you want to save the child elements rather than throwing them away, the above is how you do that. Good luck!

Comment: @MeetGondaliya your variables may be going out of scope, eg if you've defined them in a function.  So getting "lost".

Comment: No, no I defined the variables out of the function (above the function)